# How can I apply custom filters in views for django rest framework serialiser?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following three model definitions

```
class Program(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    assigned_by = models.ForeignKey('physio.Physio', null=True, blank=True)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField('patient.Patient')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(
        'exercise.Exercise')
```

Here is the serialiser

```
class ProgramSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = (
            'title', 'assigned_by', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'duration', 'description', 'exercises'
        )
```

Following is the views :

```
class ProgramViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Program.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProgramSerializer
```

I want to Get all programs assigned by a particular physio to a patient.
How should the views be altered?

The URL can be - /programs/physio/:physioID/patient/:patientID

I have used [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) for the generic list and detail views.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `.get_queryset()` method of `ProgramViewSet`

```
def get_queryset(self):

    physio = Physio.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['physioID'])
    patient = Patient.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['patientID'])

    return Purchase.objects.filter(assigned_by=physio,
                                   assigned_to=patient)
```

As described in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).